# RSVP Promises: then() chain returning the first value of the chain

Tags: javascript, promise, rsvp.js

I'm currently trying to wrap some indexedDB code into promises.

I have a "load db" function as:

```
db.load = new RSVP.Promise( function ( fulfill , reject ) {
    //...
    if (globaldb) {
        fulfill(globaldb);
        return;
    }
    //...
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        globaldb = e.target.result;
        fulfill(globaldb);
    }
});
```

My intent is to load the db the on the first DB function called, saving the reference to it and reusing it on subsequent requests.

```
db.query = function( objectStoreName , options ) {

    var queryPromise = new RSVP.Promise( function ( fulfill , reject ) {

        //... do some work
        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
            fulfill( anArray );
        }

    });

    return db.load.then(queryPromise);

}
```

Finally, trying to use the wrapper created above:

```
db.query("tablename", ... ).then( function ( data ) {
    //do things, write to the screen, etcetera
});
```

It ends up that `data` contains the value fulfilled by `db.load`, instead of the one fulfilled by `db.query`. How can I fix that? Is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are misunderstanding what the term "promise" means. A promise is not a "task", it cannot be executed or called like a function can. A promise does represent the (asynchronous) *result* of some action, it is the *return value* of a function.

If you want a "load DB" function that is called when needed, make it a *function* (that returns a promise), not a promise. If you pass a callback to `then`, pass a *function*, not a promise.

```
var globaldb = null;
db.load = function() {
    if (globaldb) {
        return globaldb;
    } else {
        return globaldb = new RSVP.Promise( function ( fulfill , reject ) {
            //...
            request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                fulfill(e.target.result);
            };
        });
    }
};
db.query = function( objectStoreName , options ) {
    return db.load().then(function(conn) {
//                ^^               ^^^^
//         call it here!       the result of loading the database
        return new RSVP.Promise( function ( fulfill , reject ) {
            //... do some work
            transaction.oncomplete = function() {
                fulfill( anArray );
            }
        });
    });
};
```